# After separating two divs using clear:both;, I can't put space between them

Tags: html, css

Here is my website, http://yetiagenda.com/submission.php.

There is no space between the radio group and the firstName input.

The two were on the same line at first, but I put "clear:both;" on the firstName.

Now, I can't put space between them.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: try to include code on site not as a link in your question

Comment: where do you want to have space?

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to your radioRole div.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following CSS in .subElse

```
    padding-top: 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @j08691 said, you need to clear the floats in your container `div`. This should work.

```
#wrap > div.content > div.submitSchool > form > ul > div.radioRole {
overflow: auto;
}
```